# Nearby search on Google Maps returns INVALID_REQUEST in Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, google-maps-api-3

I've tried to build up an application based on Springboot, in which there is request to query places based on Google map API. The final URL is print as following:

```
2023-04-21 14:23:53.417 INFO  [pool-2-thread-1] c.h.s.c.s.GoogleBackendSearcher.nearbySearch - search url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=MY_API_KEY&keyword=food&location=48.1317547%2C11.5694659&language=US&radius=1500
```

It seems OK since the same URL put into Postman and the explore, there are valid results returned. But the wired thing is that there is always response as INVALID_REQUEST when running the Springboot application. Can anyone help to share suggestions about what's the problem.

The class to build up the search URL:

```
public class GoogleBackendSearcher {
protected String autoSuggestAPI() {
    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json";
}
protected String apiKey(){
    return MY_API_KEY;
}

private boolean nearbySearch(SearchRequest request) {
    String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(autoSuggestAPI())
            .queryParam("keyword", request.getQuery())
            .queryParam("location", UriUtils.encode(String.valueOf(request.getLocation()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .queryParam("radius", request.getRadius())
            .queryParam("key", apiKey())
            .build()
            .toUriString();
    log.info("search url: {}", url);

    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);

    HttpStatus statusCode = result.getStatusCode();
    log.info("search result: {}", result.getBody());
    if (statusCode.is2xxSuccessful()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        log.error("search failed, HTTP code: {}", statusCode.value());
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you've figured this out yet, but I had the same issue tonight. I noticed that the only thing encoded in the URI we were using was the comma between longitude and latitude in the location key.

I fixed my issue and got a good response when I used an actual comma instead of using `%2C` in the location values.

So rather than: `location=48.1317547%2C11.5694659`, try using `location=48.1317547,11.5694659`.

Something else I ran into was the double dropping 0's from the end of the coordinates, so if that's something you hadn't thought through, make sure to use a DecimalFormat or something to always populate 6 decimal places.

Happy Hacking!

Comment: thanks for sharing, the problem is fixed on my side with the same solution as your's.